# Cannot echo array elements - Undefined index

Tags: php, arrays

I have my array looking like this when I `print_r(delegates[$i])`

```
Array
(
    ['firstName'] => Brady
    ['surname'] => Manning
    ['jobTitle'] => CEO
    ['memberNumber'] => 123456
    ['dieteryRequirements'] => halal
)
```

Howerver, when I try to get the firstName like this `echo delegates[$i]['firstName']` I get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined index: firstName
```

Schoolboy question but I'd really appreciate some help here.

Comment: Try: `echo delegates[$i]["'firstName'"]`

Comment: Try: `echo delegates['firstName']` :/

Comment: Where does `$i` come from? is this inside an iteration? Provide that information as well as it will help giving you a better answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After examining the error you are having, this is my best answer. I initially assumed you didnt need the index `$i`, but that was not the case since you are actually getting results when you `print_r($delegates[$i])` Therefore I am lead to believe your array is a multidimensional array.

Another thing I noticed, (and I give credit to @Rizier123 who pointed out in the comments to use both single and double quotes) is that your `print_r` result is outputting single quotes `''` around your element keys like this `'firstname'` This means that you are actually storing the quotes inside your array. With all that said I believe your `$delegates` array looks something like this:

```
$delegates = array(
    array(
        "'firstName'" => 'Brady',
        "'surname'" => 'Manning',
       "'jobTitle'" => 'CEO',
        "'memberNumber'" => 123456,
        "'dieteryRequirements'" => 'halal',
    )
);
```

Therefore in order to access the element you will need to use the index, and use the element with the single quotes `''` like this:

```
echo $delegates[0]["'firstname'"]
```

What I would do is remove all those single quotes so that you can access them correctly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks my friend, I didn't for one second pay attention to the single-quotes. Long day

Comment: I missed that initially as well. Glad I was able to help.